# Moving Java web application from JBoss to Websphere - getting exceptions when building Maven errors

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jboss, websphere

Resource annotations on the fields of the `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
```

I am also seeing some Maven dependency errors when I performed a Maven build, Can you please help how I can resolve these classpath errors

```
using spring-core-4.1.4.release.jar, spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar
```

Error #2 - This is another error being displayed, which may be related to above error,

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet [appServlet]: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet was found, but is missing another required class.
SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server.
```

Comment: Please format your question. Currently it is hard to distinguish between your text and console output

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer Formatted and added more relevant tags.

Comment: Please add pom.xml to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Your application clearly needs the Spring framework and can't find it. It either needs to be deployed as part of the EAR/WAR, or configured as a shared library in your server and mapped to your application.